# compgen:96: command not found: aws_completer when trying to autocomplete aws

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'm trying to get aws-cli autocompletion working in my zsh using `oh-my-zsh`, `fzf`, `zsh-completion` and `fzf-tab-completion`.

But when I hit tab after `aws` I get the following error:

`compgen:96:command not found: aws_completer`

This is my `.zshrc`:

```
source $HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/fzf-tab-completion/zsh/fzf-zsh-completion.sh 
zstyle ':completion:*:*:aws' fzf-search-display true

export ZSH="/Users/simon/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="half-life"


plugins=(aws fzf zsh-completions git brew npm react-native)
autoload -U compinit && compinit
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

I suspect the issue could be that I installed the aws-cli bundle from the Amazon website first and after I installed `brew install awscli` but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by uninstalling the bundle and homebrew installation like so:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/aws
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/aws
$ brew remove awscli
```

And reinstall it via homebrew:

```
$ brew install awscli
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error with terraform, when I typed `terraform state <tab>` I got the error `compgen:96: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/terraform`

but terraform was installed to `/usr/local/bin/terraform` as found by the following:

```
$ which terraform
/usr/local/bin/terraform
```

The fix was to amend the file ~/.zshrc which tells the auto complete where to find terraform. find the line `complete -o nospace -C /usr/bin/terraform terraform` and change it to `complete -o nospace -C /usr/local/bin/terraform terraform`

reload the shell `source ~/.zshrc`

now when you press tab the terraform autocomplete will work for you